# Python process multiply files

Tags: python, regex, file, process

I have question about files. How can I process 6 files with one loop.
Name of the files:

```
alj.csv.1, alj.csv.2, alj.csv.3, alj.csv.4
```

If you wondering why is extension is number, that's convertor but it's ok.
Example of my code:

```
 def alj1():
        try:
            import glob
            from datetime import datetime
            import datetime
            from datetime import timedelta, date
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='{}'.format(error_log))
            csv1 = '/opt/transcode/data/epg/output/CSV/ALJAZEERA'
            try:
                # Regex match

                for name in os.listdir(csv1):
                    if name.startswith('alje'): 
                        h1 = name
                        print h1


                        output_file = open('/opt/transcode/data/epg/output/CSV/ALJAZEERA/alj_pre.csv','w')
                        input_file  = open(r'/opt/transcode/data/epg/output/CSV/ALJAZEERA/','rb')
                        for line in input_file:
                            if re.search(r'^\".+?\",,,,,',line):
                                line_date = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}',line)[0]
                                #print line_date

                            if re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*', line):
                                line_all = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*',line)[0]
                                #print line_all
                                output_file.write(line_date+','+line_all+'\n')
                        output_file.close()

How can I process all files with extension is number, like example from above.
```

Now loop look's like:

```
csv1 = '/opt/transcode/data/epg/output/CSV/ALJAZEERA/alj.csv.[0-9]'
        files = glob.iglob(csv1) 
        try:
            # Regex match
            for name in files:
                h1 = name
                print h1


                output_file = open('/opt/transcode/data/epg/output/CSV/ALJAZEERA/alj_pre.csv','w')
                with open(h1,'r') as file:

                    for line in file:
                        if re.search(r'^\".+?\",,,,,',line):
                            line_date = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}',line)[0]
                            #print line_date
                        if re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*', line):
                            line_all = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*',line)[0]
                            #print line_all
                            output_file.write(line_date+','+line_all+'\n')
                    output_file.close() 


        except:
            logging.exception("Failed to process ALJAZEERA %s"% current_time)
```

Comment: Loop only do first file from directory, any sugesstion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported `glob`, but you never used it:

```
for filename in glob.iglob('alj.csv.[0-9]'):
    # Do something with `filename`
```

Also, move your logic into simpler functions. You'll find it easier to work with.

Comment: One question about this, I changed to this loop. But when I want to process all files, this loop give's me only first file from directory.

Comment: @Fox_01: It gives you all of them. Either your file names aren't of that form or your code exits the interpreter.

Comment: Yea, it gives all names of files in directory. But when I want loop over all files, it loop only one of them.